# Регулярка php удалить пробел?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Могут быть строки вида:

1. 3 д панель
2. панель 3 д
3. панель 3 Д
4. плитка 3 д. (может быть любой знак препинания)
5. ул. Степана Разина 23 д 3 кв 3 (23 д Не должно замениться)

Если будет 223 д или 223 дом не должно заменяться.
Нужно что бы в строке "3 д" заменилось на "3д" ли "3д.",
может быть любой знак препинания после "д".
Так же может быть большая "Д"

Помогите пожалуйста в регулярках не силен?

Comment: Переформатируйте свой ответ так, чтобы четко выделялись строки. Можно их оформить маркированным списком.

Comment: _"... в регулярках не силен."_ Тогда попробуйте свои способности в оформлении и форматировании своего вопроса. Начните со знаков препинания и переносов.

Answer (score 0):

видимо как-то так.

негативный просмотр назад, чтобы проверить что нет других цифр пред `3`. Один и более пробелов между `3` и `д` и какой-нибудь разделитель после `д`

```
$txt = preg_replace('/(?<!\d)3\s+д\b/uigm', "3д", $txt)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bflMRc/1

Comment: Регулярка неочень! не ловит в строке `ул. Степана Разина 3 д 3 кв 3`. Вперед и назад нужно ловить слова `панель` и `плитка`.

Comment: @Majestio да, есть такое. что там вперед назад ловить автору виднее. "ул. Красная плитка 3д 50кв" сломает ваш алгоритм. Ответ не претендует на полноту, но показывает направление для дальнейших действий.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал так

`$text = preg_replace('#\b(3)\s*($|[Дд])($|[ .,!?:;])?#u', '$1$2$3', $text);`

Благодарю всех за помощь!